# How can I add a new row to an existing matrix?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class matrix 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {   
        int rows = 4;
        int cols = 3;

        int[][] result = new int[rows][];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
                result[i] = new int[cols];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    System.out.print(result[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
    }
}
```

Can I do the same thing, but for rows? I want to add new rows to a single row matrix.

Comment: you can use ```Vector```s instead of array. read about it in the javadoc, and search google for some tutorials, it's simple

Answer (score 1):

No, arrays have a fixed size. You can't re-size them after they are instantiated.
Your only option (if you must use arrays, and can't use Collections such as ArrayList instead) is to create a new larger array and copy the content of the original array to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do that in Java: Once you declare an array's size, it stays fixed. You have two choices:

1. Either create a new, bigger array and copy the data from the original array to the new one
2. Use an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s